# Regex to allow apostrophe only for words ending with s

Tags: regex, input, character, apostrophe, letters

I'm using this Regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}$` to allow the following rules:
- Letters a-z
- Letters A-Z
- Numbers 0-9
- Input length must be at least 2 characters and maximum 20 characters.

I also want to allow apostrophe only at the end of words ending with s.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,18}'s)$
```

So: either your original regex, or your original regex (reduced to maximum 18 characters, you might want to change the minimum as well) ending in `"'s"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I receive false for the input user's name for example when using it in PHP - 

return preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,20}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,18}'s)$/", $this->input);